# Precompiling Jsp files at Runtime

Tags: java, web-applications, jsp

I need to find out how to precompile jsp files at Runtime for a webapplication.

The situation is this: 
Plugin's can be added to the webapplication at runtime. These plugin's can contain new jsp files or jsp files that override existing jsp's. In order to make sure that the user sees the correct version, I need to precompile the new version of this file using java code as the webserver doesn't always registers that the jsp file has been changed/added/removed and therefore it doesn't recompile the new version of the jsp file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't app server agnostic.

Comment: That's more of a serverfault question. The recompilation of any jsp at runtime depends on what kind of server you are running. For example Apache uses Jasper 2 engine and actually detects changes of any jsp in runtime. WAS needs this: <jspAttributes xmi:id="JSPAttribute_1" name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/> in ibm-web-ext.xmi

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible to compile the jsp at runtime using an embedded jsp and java compiler? We would like to do this with a custom class loader.

Answer (score 1):

Correct - Tomcat and WebLogic do it differently, as do all Java EE app servers.  You'll have different ways to do it for different products.  Fortunately, the ones I've used have Ant tasks that allow you to automate the pre-compilation step and package the .class files into your WAR.